# How To use dynamic link in haml

Tags: ruby-on-rails, haml

I am using Haml and have a header that contains a link to another page like so:

```
.heading
   = link_to community.community_tag_path(community_tag) do
```

This ultimately renders a link.

I need to embed the same link as used in the header into a generic span tag like so:

```
%span View all Articles
```

How do I use this as a link using haml? Basically, I need the same link as in the header to work with the span

Comment: Embed link into a link? Can you, please, explain more specific what you want to do?

Comment: I updated question, hopefully it makes more sense

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can pass a do block to the link_to function:

```
= link_to community.community_tag_path(community_tag) do
  %span View all Articles
```

Or if you want the span to wrap the link_to:

```
%span= link_to "View all Articles", community.community_tag_path(community_tag)
```

To display the link with the community tag's name, simply do:

```
%span= link_to community_tag.name, community.community_tag_path(community_tag)
```

Here is some documentation about link_to: http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to

---

Following the comments, to display links like "View all [community tag's name] articles", you can do a string interpolation:

```
"View all #{community_tag.name} articles"
```

And add this string as the first argument of the link_to.

Comment: What about adding dynamic text instead of view all articles, view all xxxx, which is created by community_tag.name

Comment: how to concatenate so I can enter generic copy with the community tag name? Like so: "View all [community tag] articles

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by the following:

```
.heading    
  = link_to community.community_tag_path(community_tag) do
    %span View all Articles
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can use a method inside of a string. But I prefer use directly like in the pasts comments.

```
%a{href: "#{community.community_tag_path(community_tag)}"} View all Articles
```